# Move business logic from StoredProcedures to REST API application - benefits?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, stored-procedures

Tl;dr what are the advantages of updating applications from WPF to the web?
I work for some polish software house, where work about 20 persons. In this company we develop .NET WPF application. But WPF its only front-end for us, all business logic are in stored procedures in SQL.
All clients of this company have his own SQL Server, and use our application only in local network, and client is responsible for admin it. So we sell only know-how and application. In last time we had discussion about moving our business logic from Stored Procedures to REST API, but my boss don’t see any benefits of this change.
Can You type me some real (business) benefits of update WPF aplication for new .net core rest api tech ? (it involve moving logic from stored procedures to API)

Comment: This might be a better question on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an exhaustive list but here's some things I would start thinking about..

First you'd likely be moving from a 2 tier architecture to a 3 tier architecture which is often a more flexible architecture that allows more modular code that is easier to test and maintain.

Second, a web architecture is usually easier to deploy and update.  You're no longer keeping track of bugs in old versions for example.

Third it might allow you to use a SaaS business model which are often more flexible allowing you to tailor your business model to your clients needs which can potentially open up new revenue streams.

A fourth benefit might be that web developers are often easier to find these days than WPF developers.  I don't know if that's the case in your area however...